# Ruby Program not performing as expected? If block executes despite failing the condition

Tags: ruby, if-statement

The Following program is intended to iterate over the holiday_hash, capitalise all keys and values and puts them out:

```
def all_supplies_in_holidays(holiday_hash)
  holiday_hash.each do |key, value|
  key_string = key.to_s
  key_string.capitalize!
  puts "#{key_string}:"
  value.each do |key2, value2|
    if key2 == :new_year || :fourth_of_july || :memorial_day 
     key_to_string = key2.to_s
     key_string1 = key_to_string.split
     final_array = []
     key_string1.each do |splitted_string|
     final_array = splitted_string.capitalize!
    end
    final_string = final_array.join(" ")
    print "#{final_string1}:"
  else
    key_string1 = key2.to_s
    print "#{key_string1}"
  end
  value2.each do |array_value|
    new_array_capitalized = []
    new_array_capitalized << array_value.capitalize!
    new_array.join(" ")
   end
  end
 end
end
```

The expected output format is:

```
Winter:
Christmas: Lights, Wreath
New Years: Party Hats
Summer:
Fourth of July: Fireworks, BBQ
Fall:
Thanksgiving: Turkey
Spring:
Memorial Day: BBQ
```

The holiday_hash is as follows:

```
  {
  :winter => {
    :christmas => ["Lights", "Wreath"],
    :new_years => ["Party Hats"]
  },
  :summer => {
    :fourth_of_july => ["Fireworks", "BBQ"]
  },
  :fall => {
    :thanksgiving => ["Turkey"]
  },
  :spring => {
    :memorial_day => ["BBQ"]
  }
}
```

The problem is:

1. The if block executes even if the conditions fails to evaluate to true.

Suggestions needed:

2. How can I simplify the process of capitalising symbols who have two words in them like :new_york to be capitalised to New York? (As the #capitalised method will return New york)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The `if` block executes even if the conditions fails to evaluate to `true`

Let's see:

```
key2 = :new_year
key2 == :new_year || :fourth_of_july || :memorial_day
#=> true
```

and now a key that is supposed to return `false`:

```
key2 = :thanksgiving
key2 == :new_year || :fourth_of_july || :memorial_day
#=> :fourth_of_july
```

That's not your expected result, but your assumption isn't correct either: the `if` block is executed simply because the condition is always *truthy*.

Why? Because it's equivalent to:

```
false || :fourth_of_july || :memorial_day
#=> :fourth_of_july
```

You want:

```
key2 == :new_year || key2 == :fourth_of_july || key2 == :memorial_day
#=> false
```

Or a little shorter:

```
[:new_year, :fourth_of_july, :memorial_day].include? key2
#=> false
```

---

> How can I simplify the process of capitalising symbols who have two words in them [...]

I'd `split` them by underscore, `capitalize` each word and `join` the result:

```
:new_year
  .to_s              #=> "new_year"
  .split('_')        #=> ["new", "year"]
  .map(&:capitalize) #=> ["New", "Year"]
  .join(' ')         #=> "New Year"
```

I've separated the method calls to show the intermediate results. You can write the above in one line:

```
:new_year.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "New Year"
```

Comment: Okay.. But why is that ? I have no Idea whats going on. I am more confused now.. Sorry its not because of your answere but by the fact that you just pointed out. can you please further explain why is this happening ?

Comment: @ZeeshanShafqat sorry, I was still writing my answer, check again.